# how to record video in landscape left only android

Tags: android

i want to record video in landscape left orientation only even if device is in any orientation how to do that?

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
 setDisplayOrientation(rotation);
}
```

i tried by comparing this but what degrees to rotate camera to record in landscape left only.

Thanks in adavance

Comment: change your activity orientation to landscape while recording video

Comment: i want to record video in background service and my app is also in background. and i just want to record video in landscape left